# Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoAlertPresentException: no such alert while trying to dismiss an alert using Selenium and Java

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, alert

I am facing an error as:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoAlertPresentException: no such alert
```

while trying to dismiss an alert using Selenium and Java.

Code trials:

```java
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[text()='Remove']")).click();
Thread.sleep(1000);
driver.switchTo().alert().dismiss();
System.out.println("Popup clicked!");
```

Comment: Well, as exception says, alert which is expected to be present on a page is absent. Please, check your web page. Also, please try to add more context in your question, so members can understand, what you are trying to do and what issues you faced with.

Answer (score 0):

Alerts are [JavaScript](https://www.javascript.com/) enabled elements and to locate an **alert** you need to induce *WebDriverWait* for the `alertIsPresent()` and you can use the following solution:

```
new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.alertIsPresent()).dismiss();
System.out.println("Popup clicked!");
```